# A unsolved puzzle from Number Theory/ Functional inequalities

Tags: number-theory, inequality, functional-equations, functional-inequalities, multiplicative-function

> The function $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is continuously differentiable and
>   increasing. Also, $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$.   Continuity and
>   differentiability of higher orders can be assumed if necessary.   The
>   proposition on hand is the following:
>
> > If for all integers $t>0$ and
> >     for all $r\in(0,1)$, $g(r^{t+1})>g(r)\cdot g(r^t)$, then for all
> >     $p,q\in(0,1)$, $g(pq)\geq g(p)g(q)$.

Comment: It seems to me that you need to approximate $\ln p/\ln q$ well enough by a rational number $m/n$. Then use $r=q^{1/n}$, so $r^n=q$, and $r^m$ is close to $p$ as you want. You can easily prove by induction that the given condition implies $g(r^{m+n})>g(r^m)g(r^n)$. Letting the approximation improve in the limit you get at least $g(pq)\ge g(p)g(q)$. May be another idea is needed to get the strict inequality?

Comment: Hello Jyrki, thanks for your reply. I like your idea of approximating lnp/lnq by a rational number m/n. But, I do not see how, induction would imply g(r^(m+n))>g(r^m)g(r^n).For example, g(r^(t+2))>g(r^(t+1))g(r)>g(r^t)[g(r)]^2, which does not help the induction hypothesis. Were you alluding to a different way of using induction?

Comment: Ahh! May be I just made a mistake there :-)

Comment: In your overflow posting you did not include $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$. Is this maintained?

Comment: Hello @AthanagorWurlitzer, thanks for pointing it out, I think I missed out the additional condition in the overflow posting. $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$ should still be there. I will edit the overflow post.

Comment: It is easier to visualize if you write it instead $h(0)=1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=0$, and $$h((n+1)x)>h(x)+h(nx)$$ for all $x>0$. Your question is then does it imply $$h(x+y)>h(x)+h(y).$$

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer In that case you should still use multiplication outside $h$.

Comment: @barto to go from this problem to the suggested one (and vice-versa)  write $x=-ln(r)$  and $g=\exp(h)$.

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer: Doesn't your reformulation of the hypothesis lead to an immediate contradiction?  You've somehow mixed up the change of variables.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: How does your induction work?  How do you show $g(r^5) > g(r^2) g(r^3)$?

Comment: Hey @JohnM, I think I can answer your question, but I cannot post a pdf shot on the conversation, so I am writing it down as a separate answer.

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer I think once you make a change of variables to get a additive inequality, the signs reverses, so, you get the reverse inequality. Maybe this is the point JohnM is making?

Comment: What is the source of this problem, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By setting $F(x)=-\log g(e^{-x})$ we get $F(0)=0,\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)=+\infty$ and:
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+,\forall t\in\mathbb{N},\quad F((t+1)x)-F(tx)\leq F(x)-F(0),\tag{1}$$
that is a sort of concavity condition. $(1)$ can be re-written as:
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+,\forall t\in\mathbb{N},\quad \int_{t}^{t+1} f(xt)\, dt \leq \int_{0}^{1}f(xt)\,dt.\tag{2}$$
It comes, almost by magic, that the function
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{2}{3}\exp\left(-3(x-9/2)^2\right)$$
satisfies $(1)$ and the boundary conditions, however:
$$ \int_{4}^{5}f(x)\,dx = 0.713993\ldots > 0.693147\ldots = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx, $$
so we just found a $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^+)$ counter-example.

[image: The graphics of $f(x)$]

Comment: Do you mind me asking how you approached the problem? I would really like to learn. Also, given your complicated functional form, how did you check for all the possible inequalities the function needs to satisfy?

Comment: I had a look at @doetoe's solution in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844013/additive-functional-inequality and try to found a regular function with the same characteristic; so I took $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ that suits the inequality nicely and introduced a gaussian perturbation by trial and error.

Comment: I checked the inequality by the graphical way with the aid of Mathematica. It happens that since the perturbation is concentrated between $4$ and $5$, only the small values of $t$ (the ones below $6$) are really critical, for the remaining ones the separation between $F((t+1)x)-F(tx)$ and $F(x)$ is quite neat.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you tell me what it means to check an inequality in a graphical way? I am trying to learn. as I would like to be able to do something like this myself in the future.

Comment: Just plot the graphics of the two functions and check that one is always above the other. It happens that for any value of $t$ the difference between $F((t+1)x)-F(tx)$ and $F(x)$ is large for large values of $x$ (this should be quite easy to prove "by hand"), hence the parameters choice can be completely computer-guided, in order to have a "machine proof".

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Thanks for your patience.